# C programming strtok issue

Tags: c, strtok, initializer

I am using strtok to extract 2 words from a string names[result]. I want to get the first value from the strtok and stored it into a char array named lastName and the second value into a char array named firstName. However I got an invalid initializer error for 2 lines which are indicated by the arrow when I compiled my code. How do I resolve my problem?

```
char *p = NULL;
p = strtok(names[result]," ");
char lastName[50] = p; <---
p = strtok(NULL, " ");
char firstName[50] = p; <---
printf("%s %s\n",firstName,lastName);
```

Comment: sprintf() is an option as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strtok gives the pointer to the tokenized string.

`char lastName[50] = p;` Isn't really a good thing that you are doing there. Should use strncpy() to copy the string, or if only want the pointer, then should store in another pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Array initialization in C can only use a literal, not a variable. So your code is a syntax error.

You need to use the typical `strcpy()` function to copy the string, or some of the more safe (and modern) varities, like `strlcpy()` or `snprintf()`.

You could also do the parsing and copying in one call, using `sscanf()`, with proper size specifiers in the formatting string to avoid the risk of buffer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a string to the character array like char lastName[50] = "Sample";
In this case you are trying to initialize a pointer to the character array 'char lastName[50] = p;' which is not valid.
Better you can use strcpy, memcpy function to copy the string to the character array or you can assign it in another pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are all correct in that copying the string data out will make this program work, but the reason `strtok` is so dastardly (and generally using it is considered ill-advised) is that it changes your input by inserting `NULL`s into the original string. If you're going to be using it anyway, you might as well advantage of this and just use the pointers that `strtok` is returning directly.

Of note, though, is that since the input is changed and maybe whoever passed that input into you is not expecting that, it might be better to copy the input to a separate string *first* before ever calling `strtok` on it.

Observe the output of this code to see what I mean:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char name[] = "Firstname Lastname";

  printf("Name before strtok: %s\n", name);
  char *first = strtok(name, " ");
  char *last = strtok(NULL, " ");

  printf("Token strings: first=%s last=%s\n", first, last);
  printf("Name after strtok: %s\n", name);
}
```

Produces:

```
Firstname Name before strtok: Firstname Lastname
Token strings: first=Firstname last=Firstname
Name after strtok: Firstname
```